# Unwanted line break using echo and cat

Tags: linux, macos, bash, echo, cat

I'm trying to add a line at the beginning of a file, using

```
echo 'time/F:x1:x2' | cat - file.txt>newfile.txt
```

But this produces line breaks at each line in the new file (except for after the added 'time/F:x1:x2' line). Any ideas on how to avoid this?

Comment: wait, what do you mean "produces line breaks at each line"? what does the input file look like and what does the output file look like?

Comment: Sorry, this was badly phrased, I posed a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502013/unwanted-empty-lines-using-echo-and-cat
@glennjackman

Comment: Don't pose a new question; edit the old one.

Answer (score 2):

Use `-n` to disable the trailing newline:

```
echo -n 'time/F:x1:x2' | cat - file.txt > newfile.txt
```

There are other ways, too:

```
sed '1s|^|time/F:x1:x2|' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

Comment: Or use `printf`: `printf "%s" 'time/F:x1:x2 | ... `

Comment: Let me clarify: I should have written "empty lines", not "line break". So if my input is
`line1 {linebreak}
line2 {linebreak}
line3`
my output will be
`time/F:x1:x2 {linebreak}
line1 {linebreak}
empty line {line break}
line2 {line break}
empty line {line break}
line3`

I want the first line break after time/F:x1:x2, but not the empty lines.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
{ echo 'time/F:x1:x2'; cat file.txt; } >newfile.txt
```

or

```
sed '1i\
time/F:x1:x2' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

Comment: I think the `{ echo …; cat; }` compound command would still produce the unwanted newline.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `echo -n`?  +1 for the use of the `{}` command grouping to make this more readable

Comment: The question is ambiguous: "I'm trying to add a line at the beginning of a file"

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't even need the `echo` and pipe if you're using bash. Just use a herestring:

```
<<< 'time/F:x1:x2' cat - file.txt > newfile.txt
```

Comment: This'll insert a newline, same as `echo` without `-n`, no?

Comment: Hmm, suppose it does, at that. I'll leave it here until OP clarifies *produces line breaks at each line*.